# ansible s3_sync take local file path instead of remote

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

Im using ansible to copy files to AWS s3. The ansible script is used for entire project deployment. So the `host` value is some remote host. I've added s3_sync module in the script.

```
- name: Deploy user guides to S3 bucket
  hosts: appservers
  s3_sync:
    bucket: "{{ aws_s3_bucket }}"
    file_root: /folder/reports
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_s3_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_s3_secret_key }}"
    region: "{{ aws_s3_region }}"
    permission: private
```

The `file_root` parameter is taking path of the remote machine rather than my local machine. Can I make it take path of my local ?

Comment: [`file_root` - File/directory path for synchronization. This is a local path.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/s3_sync_module.html) So why do you run this task on `appservers`?

Comment: If its a local path. Shouldn't it take my local path. As I said my script is used for different deployment functions thus a group is created appservers for that.

Comment: Why do you run this task on a machine that does not have `/folder/reports`?